# How render one react app in another react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react applications:
- first application is a application for a different posts, for example we have some list of posts and can open each post to read and so on.
- second application is a widget for comments, it described as a widget because it could be used in different places and in different applications but will have one logic.

I use some providing function for mount this widget, it looks like:

```
export default function (mountPoint) {
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <SomeContainer />
    </Provider>,
    mountPoint
);
```

And in my first application, when i open some post, I mount it using **componentDidMount** method and **ref** on my DOM element.

On this step i have no problems with connecting this two applications.
But... when i try to open another post i have to remove previous comments widget and mount new. My component which render post doesn't unmount, just get new props. Of course I can get new props and compare for example id previous and new post. But how can I unmount previous widget app and mount new on the same DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize both components in one app along side [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

It would look something like this...

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Component1}/>
  <Route path="/path" component={Component2}/>
</Router>
```

[Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) is an additional resource regarding react-router use cases.